# Bing Maps route poly line can not be removed from map

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have the following xaml to bind an instance of the class `LocationCollection` to an instance of the class `MapPolyline`.

```
 <Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:MapPolyline Stroke="Green"
                                            Locations="{Binding Points}"
                                            StrokeThickness="6"
                                            Opacity="0.7" />
```

The `Points` property is defined in the ViewModel as:

```
public LocationCollection Points
{
    get
    {
        return this.points;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetPropertyAndNotify(ref this.points, value, "Points");
    }
}
```

Now when I set the `Points` property the route line is displayed as expected but when I want to remove the line with the following code the line is still displayed - even though I've created a new empty `LocationCollection` class and notify the property has changed.

Anyone got any idea why the route line is not removed?

```
this.Points = new LocationCollection();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is setting the collection to a new instance or clearing the current collection completely is wrong, what I had to do was remove all but the first item from the collection.

e.g.

```
private void ResetPoints()
{
    if (this.Points.Count() > 0)
    {
        var firstPoint = this.Points.First();
        this.Points.Clear();
        this.Points.Add(firstPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create route layer with this

```
MapLayer route_layer = new MapLayer();
```

create line with MapPolyline such as

```
MapPolyline routeLine = new MapPolyline()
        {
            Locations = locs,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(c),
            StrokeThickness = 5
        };
```

add to your route layer and then map with this

```
route_layer.Children.Add(routeLine);
MyMap.Children.Add(route_layer);
```

**remove** from your map with this.

```
MyMap.Children.Remove(route_layer);
```